# Oracle APEX 5 Calendar Region Create Link URL Issue

Tags: oracle-apex-5

There seems to be problem with Calendar region in APEX 5. When I set Create Link property with target type as URL and URL value with some JavaScript function, then I get following runtime error when I run the page.

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one region and select the region type is calendar
2. Create the sql query like display value and date (select description, des_date from followup )
3. Click the attibutes and select the settig tab assign the display name in Description and start column in des_date,
4. Run the page you will get the output

[click here to see the example screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v62yn.png)